# AngularJS Testing - Testing Out Logic in Promise Callback

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have the following function in my controller:

```
$scope.submitNote = function(){
    myService.addNote($scope.note).then(function(data){
        if(data.success === true){
            $scope.note = null;
        }
        else{
            // API call failed
        }
    }, function(){
        // Promise call failed
    });
};
```

I set up my testing environment with:

```
// Mock out fake service
beforeEach(function(){
    myService = {
        addNote: function(){
            deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({
                success: true
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    spyOn(myService, 'addNote').and.callThrough();
});

// Assign controller scope
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q){
    q = $q;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('myController', {
        $scope: scope,
        myService: myService
    });
}));
```

Then test out my `submitNote()` function with:

```
describe('submitNote Test', function(){
    it('should set scope.note to null after successful service call', function(){
        scope.submitNote();
        expect(myService.addNote).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.note).toBe(null);
    });
});
```

The first `expect` passes, but the second `expect` does not.  It looks like the `then()` callback from my `submitNote()` function isn't being called in the test.

How do I make sure the promise callback in the original function is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you cleaner tests that you have more control over the `ngMock` module extends various core services so they can be inspected and controlled in a synchronous manner.

Promise callbacks are executed during the digest loop, which in your testing environment you need to start manually.

For example:

```
describe('submitNote Test', function () {
    it('should set scope.note to null after successful service call', function () {

        scope.submitNote();
        scope.$digest();

        expect(myService.addNote).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.note).toBe(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: [SitePoint: Understanding Angular’s $apply() and $digest()](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)